# Speeding up listbox insertion time

Tags: c#, winforms, .net-2.0, listbox

I need to add 950 strings that are 2500 characters in length to a listbox.  The method I am using below takes 2.5 seconds and ideally it needs to happen in less then 500ms.

```
Stopwatch sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();

listBox1.BeginUpdate();
listBox1.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
listBox1.EndUpdate();

sw.Stop();
```

What would be the best way to optimize the insertion time?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you could try is changing this line:

```
listBox1.Items.AddRange(items.ToArray());
```

to something like this:

```
foreach (var item in items)
{
    listBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

That way, you do not have the overhead of creating a whole new array (the `ToArray()` call) before putting the items into your `ListBox`.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, that takes the same amount of time as the addrange method.

Comment: @Eric: Hmm...ok.  Do you happen to have Visual Studio 2010 and its profiler or have access to another profiler that could tell you where the most time is being spent in those lines?

Comment: Using the profiler included with vs2010 it appears that all the time is being spent in the `Add` or `AddRange` methods.

Answer (score 1):

Listbox is dealing with 2500 characters. That is what is slow. All that data, including converting to/from arrays, is peanuts in memory. Hence skipping the ToArray step not making a difference. If your users have to scroll horizontally to see this info, chances are, you're stuck with 'slow.'

If not, consider refactoring a tiny bit. Strategy: only put as many characters - about 100 - as are viewable in a regular width listbox. Full strings are retained behind the scenes.

- Make a helper class like so (you can convert the public string to a property if you're that anal;-):

```
    Class TruncatedListItem
        Public Content as string
        Overrides sub ToString() as string ' Pardon me if this is wrong I always use intellisense
            return Mid(Content,1,100)
        end sub
    end class
```

- Add those items to the listbox. When an item in a listbox isn't of type string, it calls the item's ToString method (which hey, we just tailored to give the listbox a break) and adds that as a string, then the items collection appears as the items you've added. (keep the begin/end update too)

  ```
  For each each itm as string in Items
      dim tli as new TruncatedListItem
      tli.Content = itm
      listbox.add(tli)
  next
  ```
- When you want to see what the user picked, instead of getting the string like this:

  ```
  MyString = Ctype(Listbox.SelectedItem,string)
  ```
- do this  

  MyString = Ctype(ListBox.SelectedItem,TruncatedListItem).Content
- Now I am assumming the user, at some point, still *needs* to see all 2500 chars before selecting. Unless they are a serious stick in the mud, they should settle for this alternative (In fact there are advantages to scrolling).

  - When they double click an item, in the handler for double click, show them the full text in a messagebox. You could tell them to do that in a tooltip. For example, in the double-click handler:  msgbox Ctype(ListBox.SelectedItem,TruncatedListItem).Content,,"Full Item Text"

Good luck!

Comment: I'm not at a Pc with .net on it so apologies if it doesn't actually speed things up. But I can't see how it won't. Thumb your nose at me if I'm wrong!!